# How to import PKCS#8 on Linux and MacOS - CngKey.Import is not available

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, jwt, cng

I'm trying to send Apple push notification using HTTP/2 APNS. For this I need to work with certificates and encryption. My code to create JWT token:

```
private string CreateJwtToken()
{
    var header = JsonHelper.Serialize(new { alg = "ES256", kid = p8privateKeyId });
    var payload = JsonHelper.Serialize(new { iss = teamId, iat = ToEpoch(DateTime.UtcNow) });

    var key = CngKey.Import(Convert.FromBase64String(p8privateKey), CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob);
    using (var dsa = new ECDsaCng(key))
    {
        dsa.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
        var headerBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header));
        var payloadBasae64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload));
        var unsignedJwtData = $"{headerBase64}.{payloadBasae64}";
        var signature = dsa.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(unsignedJwtData));
        return $"{unsignedJwtData}.{Convert.ToBase64String(signature)}";
    }
}
```

While this works well on Windows, `CngKey.Import` is not supported on Linux and MacOS. How can I rewrite this code to make it cross-platform?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting with .NET Core 3.0, all AsymmetricAlgorithm types support PKCS#8 key imports.

```
private string CreateJwtToken()
{
    var header = ...;
    var payload = ...;

    using (ECDsa key = ECDsa.Create())
    {
        key.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(p8privateKey), out _);

        string headerBase64 = ...;
        string payloadBase64 = ...;
        string unsignedJwtData = ...;
        byte[] encodedRequest = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(unsignedJwtData);

        byte[] signature = key.SignData(encodedRequest, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);

        return $"{unsignedJwtData}.{Convert.ToBase64String(signature)}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your input. I'll try it!